# Custom Overflow-x CSS width and position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I made some researchs and I need some help, I've got an horizontal slider on Bootstrap 4 and I need a scroll bar on top and center it so I need to change the position, a small one so I need to change the width.

I know how to change the width but if it's overflow-y and not overflow-x and I don't know how to change the position.

Here's is my code :

```css
/* line 6, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Track */
  /* Handle */
}
/* line 9, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row > .col-sm-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
/* line 13, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
/* line 17, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/* line 24, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* line 30, sass/page/_home.scss */
.employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid employes">
  <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if I've got an answer only with CSS.
By the way, do you know how to make it multi platform ? I've tried putting -ms-, -o- instead of -webkit- or -webkit-appereance:none but it didn't work.

**EDIT :** This is what I mean 
[image]

Comment: _I've got an horizontal slider on Bootstrap 4 and I need a scroll bar on top and center it so I need to change the position, a small one so I need to change the width._ -- could you please provide more explicit explanation of desired effect? What scrollbar are you talking about? You call red scrollbar _slider_, so I assume it's not a _scollbar_ you address.

Comment: I edited my question, I'm not really good with english so I made a picture to explain you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that ::-webkit-scrollbar selectors are supported only by webkit, so on non-webkit browsers (for example Firefox) styled scrollbars and below trick won't work. It is currently not possible to style scrollbars with pure CSS in non-webkit browsers.

**[As of 25-06-2018]**

---

Thank you for clarifying desired effect. 'Image speaks a thousand words', as they say.

In below solution I combined two tricks. One is use of `transform: rotateX(180deg)` for container and columns, so scrollbar appears on top of div, and not on bottom (as default). Second `transform: rotateX(180deg)` rotates columns to default orientation. To make scrollbar shorter I styled scrollbar buttons. They have width, but are invisible, so it looks like scrollbar body is shorter.

```
.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

I hope that helps.

```css
/* line 6, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.employes>.row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  /* Track */
  /* Handle */
}


/* line 9, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes>.row>.col-sm-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


/* line 13, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}


/* line 17, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* line 24, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* line 30, sass/page/_home.scss */

.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.employes>.row::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid employes">
  <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did the transform:rotateX(180deg) trick but somehow I messed up something, it works well now !

Comment: Please remember that `::-webkit-scrollbar` selectors are supported only by webkit, so on non-webkit browsers (for example Firefox) styled scrollbars and above trick won't work. It is currently not possible to style scrollbars with pure CSS in non-webkit browsers.

Comment: How can I do in non-webkit browsers to have the same effects which work on all browsers ? Do you have a JS, CSS tricks to recommand me ?

Comment: You need to search for custom-scrollbars JS libraries / plugins, only they can create cross-browser custom scrollbars ([first result in Google](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/top-7-custom-scrollbar-javascript-and-jquery-plugins/)). [I actually asked question here on SO if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish that without JS, but it nobody (yet) came up with anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036626/css-scrollbar-that-doesnt-have-100-height-width).