# CSS: scrollbar that doesn't have 100% height / width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to force vertical scrollbar to have less than 100% height of scrollable div it's part of **with pure CSS and for all modern browsers except IE**?

So far all I came up with is *webkit-only* solution with it's `::-webkit-scrollbar` CSS selectors, and trick for custom buttons height, like so:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: transparent;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to trick `.parent` with `transform: scale` in only one direction, so to shrink parent and grow content with same value, like so:

```
.parent {
    transform: scale(0.5, 1);
}

.child {
    transform: scale(2, 1);
}
```

... but it doesn't work, as child can't extend parent's dimensions without position absolute, which makes it invisible for parent, and scrollbar unnecessary.

If there is any other way around, I'm all ears, as I prefer CSS over additional JS plugins / librariers / packages.

**It's CSS-only question**. I know there are JS plugins that can create whatever scrollbar I want.

Comment: what are you really try to achieve?

Comment: Same effect as in posted snippet, but for more browsers than just webkits.

Comment: You can't do that with pure css as there is no cross browser equivalent to ::-webkit-scrollbar etc. You're going to need JS.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I hoped you guys here could see a way I have not.

Comment: There is no css only way to achieve this across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece** to customize the top-most layer of the the progress bar. In this case it will not be on 100% of the parent height.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: transparent;
  /*height: 25%;*/
}


/* this will do the trick */
.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```