# How to Give a Fixed Height to the Scroller without Increasing the Page Content?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollview

Here I'm trying to give a fixed height to the scroller that independent of page content height. I added my codes below.

```css
section#data-container{
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #000;
    
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    /*height: 30px;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<section id="data-container">
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g

ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
</section>
```

and which is appearing just like show on the image displayed below
[image]

I would like to decrease the width and set it as fixed. Can anybody help me?

Comment: [I asked similar question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036626/css-scrollbar-that-doesnt-have-100-height-width), but there is no solution for it, only webkit-only trick I presented there.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek oh sorry. I really meant the scroller

Comment: what you want exactly, do you dont want to show scroll? or you want scroller

Comment: @charankumar I would like to give a fixed size to my scroller that independent of the content height

Comment: I dont think so we can change the height of the scroller, it is always based on the height of the content, we can control only the width

Comment: @charankumar let us hope somebody come with some tricky codes ...maybe some tricky codes can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try give `min-height` in `data-container`.

```
section#data-container{
    min-height:400px;
    width:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #000;

}
```

code on snippet

```css
section#data-container{
    min-height:400px;
    width:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #000;
    
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    /*height: 30px;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<section id="data-container">
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g

ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
adsgdhhhhhhjkhjdhjkfkl fdjhkl;jkh hjhjfdhklh 
ghdfjkgjkfkfh hkdjhfklh khfklhgdlfk flk;jl;g
jhgfdhjl;jljl jkfjkl;gj ljl;kjl;j ljlkjfuirui
</section>
```

Comment: how can the data-container affect scroller height? and where you have given the fixed height to the scroller?

Comment: try increase the min-height value.

Comment: Or else, put the elements in a div and give min-height to that div.

Comment: And check how your code is working...I have added that on a snippet.it's hide the scroller completely.